# Does this life end, or do I keep having to Fix-It?

Tags: fix-it-felix-jr

Does the Arcade game: [Fix-it Felix Jr.](http://thegaminghistorian.com/fix-it-felix-jr-review/) have an ending or last level?  Because it seems like it's going on forever, and I keep say: "I can fix it!".  Does this last forever?  The answer can be either the Arcade game or the Mobile game.

Comment: If it's anything like other old 80's games, it just keeps on going.

Comment: @fbueckert But but but in the movie he makes it to the top and then there's cake! Was that cake a lie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the game never ends, you just keep on climbing up the apartment building.